# З ссылки(YAML) достать определенную информацию?

Tags: python-3.x, requests, yaml

Здраствуйте.
Пишу приложение на Python и столкнулся с одной проблемой. У меня есть статическая YAML-ссылка в которой есть информация про товар и с нее как то надо достать инфу и закинуть в таблицу.

Вот мой код:

```
import requests
import yaml

url = 'ссылка'

payload = {}
headers = {}

r = requests.request("GET", url, headers = headers, data = payload)

with open(r.text, 'r') as yml:
    data = yaml.safe_load(yml)

print(data)
```

Вот что я получаю на выходе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можна пофиксить ети символи и извлекать данные?

Comment: Попробовать указать кодировку при открытии файла на чтение.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов не помогло

Comment: Добавил `encoding='UTF-8'`

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/147843/. Попробуйте `cp1252`.

Comment: 1 - Перед чтением из ответа пропишите кодировку в самом ответе: `r.encoding = 'utf-8'`. 2 - вы пытаетесь использовать прочитанные данные как имя файла, а нужно не открывать ничего через open, а просто передать текст ответа в safe_load: `data = yaml.safe_load(r.text)`. 3 - то что в консоли не похоже на yaml, это скорее всего xml.

Comment: *>Вот что я получаю на выходе* - а это, вообще, выход чего? Это какая-то ошибка? Или результат принта?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Результат принта

Comment: @insolor спасибо теперь оно начало работать, но уже ошибки по построении файла, пойду исправлять)